# Local storage in Twig

Tags: templating, javascript

Quick question: Is it possible to access the browser's local storage in Twig?

In JavaScript you would do something like:

```
localStorage.getItem('myItem');
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Twig gets compiled into PHP and is run entirely on the server.